# Print whole line with highest value from one column

Tags: linux, shell, awk, aix

I have a little issue right now.
I have a file with 4 columns

```
test0000002,10030010330,c_,218
test0000002,10030010330,d_,202
test0000002,10030010330,b_,193
test0000002,10030010020,c_,178
test0000002,10030010020,b_,170
test0000002,10030010330,a_,166
test0000002,10030010020,a_,151
test0000002,10030010020,d_,150
test0000002,10030070050,c_,119
test0000002,10030070050,b_,99
test0000002,10030070050,d_,79
test0000002,10030070050,a_,56
test0000002,10030010390,c_,55
test0000002,10030010390,b_,44
test0000002,10030010380,d_,41
test0000002,10030010380,a_,37
test0000002,10030010390,d_,35
test0000002,10030010380,c_,33
test0000002,10030010390,a_,31
test0000002,10030010320,c_,30
test0000002,10030010320,b_,27
test0000002,10030010380,b_,26
test0000002,10030010320,a_,23
test0000002,10030010320,d_,22
test0000002,10030010010,a_,6
```

and I want the highest value from 4th column sorted from 2nd column.

```
test0000002,10030010330,c_,218 
test0000002,10030010020,c_,178 
test0000002,10030010330,a_,166 
test0000002,10030010020,a_,151 
test0000002,10030070050,c_,119 
test0000002,10030010390,c_,55 
test0000002,10030010380,d_,41 
test0000002,10030010320,c_,30 
test0000002,10030010390,a_,31 
test0000002,10030010380,c_,33 
test0000002,10030010390,d_,35 
test0000002,10030010320,a_,23 
test0000002,10030010380,b_,26 
test0000002,10030010010,a_,6
```

Comment: How is this `test0000002,10030010330,a_,166` getting into your output, they will be filtered out by the sort ! Also explain in a little more detail, what you mean by "highest from 4th column sorted from 2nd column" ?

Comment: sorry, my mistake.

Comment: Post your expected output.

Comment: Why is the line with `166` included? Its 2nd column number is already present with 218.

Comment: @choroba 10 minutes later... :-)

Comment: @iamauser: I thought the post was edited in the meantime...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your file is already sorted in descending order on the 4th column, so you just need to print lines where the 2nd column appears for the first time:

```
awk -F, '!seen[$2]++' file
```

```
test0000002,10030010330,c_,218
test0000002,10030010020,c_,178
test0000002,10030070050,c_,119
test0000002,10030010390,c_,55
test0000002,10030010380,d_,41
test0000002,10030010320,c_,30
test0000002,10030010010,a_,6
```

If your input file is not sorted on column 4, then

```
sort -t, -k4nr file | awk -F, '!seen[$2]++'
```

Comment: Is your input file pre-sorted or not? Your sample data is pre-sorted.

Comment: Thank you my friend. This worked.
sort -t, -k4nr file | awk -F, '!seen[$2]++'

Answer (score 0):

You can use two sorts:

```
sort -u -t, -k2,2 file | sort -t, -rnk4
```

The first one removes duplicates in the second column, the second one sorts the first one on the 4th column.

Comment: The same result. It's always printing the same 3rd column. a_ for all 7 lines.

test0000002,010030010330,a_,166
test0000002,010030010020,a_,151
test0000002,010030070050,a_,56
test0000002,010030010380,a_,37
test0000002,010030010390,a_,31
test0000002,010030010320,a_,23
test0000002,010030010010,a_,6

Comment: Then please better explain how the lines should be sorted.